# Does StackOverflow use OpenID Connect for Google log in?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm trying to gain a better understanding of OAuth2 and OpenID Connect so I decided to see what shows up in Chrome's developer tools when I sign in to StackOverflow with my Google account.

After clicking on the Google button to sign in, these 5 network requests are made:

*Note that I'm already signed in to Google and have previously authorized StackOverflow.*

```
1) 204 POST https://stackoverflow.com/gps/event
    Request Payload:
        ...
        properties:
            location: "users_login"
            openid_provider: "google"

2) 302 POST https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?...
    Query String Parameters:
        ssrc: head
        returnurl: https://stackoverflow.com/
    Form Data:
        email: 
        password: 
        oauth_version: 2.0
        oauth_server: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
        openid_username: 
        openid_identifier: 

3) 302 GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?...
    Query String Parameters:
        client_id: xxxx
        scope: profile email
        redirect_uri: https://stackauth.com/auth/oauth2/google
        state: {"sid":1,"st":"xxxx","ses":"xxxx"}
        response_type: code


4) 302 GET https://stackauth.com/auth/oauth2/google?...
    Query String Parameters:
        state: {"sid":1,"st":"xxxx","ses":"xxxx"}
        code: xxxx


5) 302 GET https://stackoverflow.com/users/oauth/google?...
    Query String Parameters:
        code: xxxx
        state: {"sid":1,"st":"xxxx","ses":"xxxx"}
        s: xxxx
```

From request 1) it looks like OpenID Connect is used.
But then looking at request 3), the scope that is requested is `scope: profile email`.

If OpenID Connect was actually used wouldn't `openid` be included in the scope? Without it the `token` endpoint will **not** return an `id_token` right?

Does this mean that StackOverflow is not actually using OpenID Connect to authenticate users that sign in with Google, but is instead leveraging plain old OAuth2?

If so I'm assuming plain old OAuth2 was commonly used for authentication (in a secure manner) before OpenID Connect came into existence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like StackOverflow is doing plain OAuth 2.0 authorization_code flow with Google as the provider.

Request 1) is going to StackOverflow server. It doesn't really mean anything. You can see that if you press on Facebook you will get
`openid_provider: "facebook"` even though Facebook doesn't implement OpenID Connect.

StackOverflow is implementing something similar to this: 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow
but just using redirects instead of using Google library

OAuth 2.0 authorization_code flow explained:
https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/#web-server-apps

Comment: Thank for the useful links. This part from your [first link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) is interesting _"If you requested profile access, you also get an ID token that contains basic profile information for the user."_. So the `profile` scope seems to have the same (or at least similar) effect as the `openid` scope. I guess before OpenID Connect existed Google had already implemented its own similar OAuth2 extension to add authentication capabilities.

Comment: From [this page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) there's this interesting bit: _" If you want to provide a "Sign-in with Google" button for your website or app, we recommend using Google Sign-In, our sign-in client library that is built on the OpenID Connect protocol and provides OpenID Connect formatted ID Tokens"_. Which basically contradicts what we see in the first link and what the network requests reveal in my question.

Comment: And from [this page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect), which is also part of Google Identity's documentation along with the other pages, another interesting bit: _"To be OpenID-compliant, you must include the openid profile scope in your authentication request."_. It's almost as though in Google's implementation the `profile` scope is what google's authorization server is really looking for to replay with an id_token, and the `openid` scope can/should be added only for the sake of being spec compliant. But don't take my word for it.

Comment: So the `profile` scope value is also defined in the OpenID Connect spec, in addition to the `openid` scope value.

Section 5.4: `profile`: _OPTIONAL. This scope value requests access to the End-User's default profile Claims_.


Section 3.1.2.1:`openid`: _REQUIRED. OpenID Connect requests MUST contain the openid scope value. If the openid scope value is not present, the behavior is entirely unspecified_.

Comment: If you use the Google library you get id_token anyway. I didn't find it in their documentation but this is the behavior I encountered on my site. But StackOverflow uses redirect instead of the client SDK I guess that why we don't see any id_token. Anyway, they will get an id_token on the server when exchanging the code for an access token. You can try yourself and see in the [playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) that after exchange you will have id_token JWT.